# PHP IMAP "FROM" authenticity

Tags: php, gmail-imap

I have a PHP script that periodically checks emails from Google apps email, it then looks at who the email is from and allocates that email to their account on our platform:

```
$inbox = imap_open(gHost,gUser,gPass) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$criteria ="ALL"; 
$emails = imap_search($inbox, $criteria);

foreach($emails as $email_number) { //loop all emails
$header = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $email_number);
$from = $header->from[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->from[0]->host;
//sql script here to check against users table and allocate the email
}
```

The problem is anyone can write a script to send an email to our platform with a false "from" and provided that email is an user on our platform it will allocate the email to that user which opens up a security hole. We already tested this and the email successfully came through. How can we check that the from user has actually been sent from that person - maybe it could be a grading using DKIM, spf, etc.

Any idea what is the best way to check authenticity?

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `From` email field is configurable.

You can think of it as a field similar to the subject lets say.
I mean anybody with the right knowledge can put anything there.

On the other hand Gmail as general rule has very good SPAM filters, so this should not happen very often.

If this happens too often and is a issue, then you should implement some additional filtering.
For example create database with the most abused emails and do some extra processing.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt really help - there must be a good way to check that the from email is authentic in the headers

Answer (score 0):

*I know, the question is several years old, but I accidentally found that question on a google search and I hope I can help others finding that page.*

### TL;DR

- The `From`-header can be set by the sender with nearly every text.
- **SPF** and **DKIM** can be used to verify that the e-mail really comes from the specified sender.
- SPF and DKIM only work if the senders administrator configured it.

---

As the thread creator and Antoan Milkov already mentioned can the sender generally use nearly every e-mail address or text in the `From`-header.

#### SPF

To verify the senders ip address is allowed to send mails in the name of the `From`-sender SPF can be used. But SPF is most time not configured by default and needs to be set by the domain administrator.

More details: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

I did not use it yet, but perhabs this is helpful to check SPF in PHP:
https://github.com/Mika56/PHP-SPF-Check

#### DKIM

With DKIM e-mails are signed by the sender and the receiver can check if the signature is valid. Also DKIM needs to be configured by the domain administrator.

More details: https://www.dmarcanalyzer.com/de/dkim-de/

Perhabs this helps for verifing DKIM signature with PHP:
https://github.com/angrychimp/php-dkim